# problem with testing service in the nestjs

Tags: testing, jestjs, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I am testing my quiz api in nestjs, and I want to test my basic answer service but test 'should be defined' failed, I am starting with jest and i understand concept of mocking methods to test resolvers (that is grapql API) but its hard for me to setup basic providers.

I have something like this:

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Answer } from './entities/answer.entity';
import { DeepPartial } from 'typeorm';
import { CreateAnswerInput } from './dto/create-answer.input';

@Injectable()
export class AnswerService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Answer)
    private readonly answerRepository: Repository<Answer>,
  ){}

  async createAnswer(question_id: number, createAnswerInput: CreateAnswerInput): Promise <Answer>{
    const { answer_content, is_correct, priority } = createAnswerInput;

    const answer: DeepPartial<Answer> = {
      question: {id: question_id},
      answer_content,
      is_correct,
      priority,
    };

    const savedAnswer = await this.answerRepository.save(answer);

    return savedAnswer;
  }

  async getAnswers(questionId: number): Promise <Answer[]>{
      return this.answerRepository.find({where: { question: { id: questionId } }})
  }
}
```

my service.spec:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Any, DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { AnswerService } from './answer.service';
import { Answer } from './entities/answer.entity';

describe('AnswerService', () =\> {
let service: AnswerService;

beforeEach(async () =\> {
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
providers: \[AnswerService, Answer\]
}).compile();

    service = module.get<AnswerService>(AnswerService)

});

it('should be defined', () =\> {
expect(service).toBeDefined();
});

describe('createAnswer', () =\> {
it('should create and return new answer', async () =\> {
const newAnswer = await service.createAnswer(1, { answer_content: "content", priority: 1, is_correct: null })

      expect(newAnswer).toEqual({
        id: expect.any(Number),
        answer_content: "content",
        priority: 1,
        is_correct: null,
        question: {id: 1}
      })
    });

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a mock repository for the `Answer` entity. Something as basic as

```js
{
  provide: getRepositoryToken(Answer),
  useValue: {}
}
```

should work for the `isDefined` test, but you'll need to provide your own method mocks for anything more complex.

[This repository has a lot of testing examples with NestJS](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)

Comment: I tried it before but i dont understand how can I test my methods, not resolvers. so i need to implement method mock for find and save?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you need to mock what methods you call to test the logical unit of the method

Comment: last question because im sure in 99%, from your typeORM-sample repo i noticed that i can just provide object which will be for founded with .find() Is it right?
I need to just provide objects or arrays which will be returned with this methods because its just work like that. Thank you

Comment: Yep. Best to return data similar to what you expect to ensure your logic is correct, but you could theoretically return anything to see how your application handles it